# Can I convert/cast a simple object to Realm object in JAVA?

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-migration

I am writing a wrapper class in java for Realm. Can I convert Plain Object to RealmObject by having same names and data type of variables in the classes?
For example

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private int age;


    public int getAge() { return age; }

    public void setAge(int age) { this.age = age; }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

To

```
public class RelamPerson extends RealmObject{

    private String name;
    private int age;


    public int getAge() { return age; }

    public void setAge(int age) { this.age = age; }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

Comment: why don't you let `Person` extend `RealmObject` directly ?

Comment: @Blackbelt. Person might be used in non-Realm code, so it is reasonable question.

Comment: well if you write the mapper code that maps one object to the other and vice versa, then yes, sure ~ but with casting, no

Comment: You can use a class which extends RealmObject as a POJO. When you do `Person person = new Person()` you will have a plain object which is not managed by Realm (that's why it's called an unmanaged object). When you need to transfer it to Realm, the `copyToRealm()` method is your new best friend :-)